# NullPointerException Error when adding a Google Maps Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have created an app with a bottom sheet, and am now trying to put a google maps fragment in it.

I have typed all the  Manifest permissions and dependencies. Here is my code for the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Button eventListButton;
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomsheetbehvior;
    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    Context context;
    public List<Events> events;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        events = new ArrayList<Events>();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Find Button
        eventListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventlistbutton);

        //Find bottom sheet
        android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView bottomsheet =
                (android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);

        //Add bottomsheet behavior to view
        mBottomsheetbehvior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheet);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setHideable(true);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setPeekHeight(400);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        eventListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    eventListButton.setText("Hide");
                }
                else if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    eventListButton.setText("Event List Button");
                }
                else if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    eventListButton.setText("Peek");
                }
            }
        });

        //Bottomsheet callbacks
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Peek");
                }
                else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Hide");
                }
                else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Event List Button");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });

        //Recyler View
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

        //Temporary Data
        String[] participants = {"Tamim","Chiharu","Azmain","Miyoshi","Steve Jobs","Michael Jackson","手塚治虫"};

        //Temporary Data
        events.add(new Events(1302719286,"U22 project",participants,new LatLng(37.652832,219.839478),"Saizeriya"));
        events.add(new Events(1502419296,"U22 project",participants,new LatLng(32.652832,19.839478),"Hiroo"));
        events.add(new Events(1901719266,"U22 project",participants,new LatLng(19.652832,39.839478),"Canada"));
        events.add(new Events(1204219286,"U22 project",participants,new LatLng(100.652832,13.839478),"Tokyo Monorail"));
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(this,events);

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng school = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(school).title("Sample Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(school));
    }
}
```

This causes a Null Pointer Exception error, at the place where I typed:

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Here is the error:

```
08-16 11:48:18.905 8997-8997/com.example.android.gatheraround E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.gatheraround, PID: 8997
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.gatheraround/com.example.android.gatheraround.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.android.gatheraround.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please do note that I have tried commenting out the "Async" method, and the map loads perfectly fine. However, it does not move at all.

Here is my Layout File if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            />
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="EventList Button"
                    android:id="@+id/eventlistbutton"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@color/recyclerview_background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/recyclerviewhorizontalpadding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/recyclerviewhorizontalpadding"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You've got the wrong `Fragment` class specified in your layout. It should be `"com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`, not `"com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`.

Comment: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment